# Adding a notification to the status bar

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How can I get a scroll bar running on the status Bar at the bottom having the current time and the text placed based on the time in the program.

I am able to get a pop-up using:

```
notifications.notify({
```

Not sure how to repeat this every 5minutes. (or) to redirect that from pop up to have in status BAR

Answer (score 0):

For that sort of functionality, you need the widget module:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/widget.html

Widgets can contain an html document.